# c# - Is there a way to assign void method to a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a repository which contains some methods. However I have a method that I am trying to assign to a variable. But it doesn't work because the method is a void. Is there anyway I can work around this problem?

Codesnippet from my controller:

```
 public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == 0 || id == 5)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var model = new Inventory();
            model = repository.FindInventoryById(id); //This line doesn't work


            if (model == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Codesnippet from my repository:

```
public void FindInventoryById(int? id) 
        {
            db.Inventories.Find(id);
        }
```

Comment: How about returning something?

Comment: Looks like you need to change your method to not use `void` so you can return what you found.

Comment: Why would you have a find method that doesn't return something?

Comment: You have to use some jump statement, but in a void method that can't work. Find out more about it, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements).

Comment: @osfresia you linked a document about jump statements which as far as I can tell has nothing whatsoever to do with this question - Tim's comment on the other hand absolutely does

Comment: @Jamiec, _The `return` statement terminates execution of the function in which it appears and returns control and the function's result, if any, to the caller._ That's why I linked this reference.

Comment: You can assign a method to a variable, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do. `Action<int?> method = FindInventoryById;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be very confused by the basics of the language you're using, which is fine we all start somewhere with programming, however I suggest you go back and read up on the basics of method calls, and returning values from methods.

For the sake of moving you along with *this* task you should make your method have a return type of `Inventory` and return it

```
public Inventory FindInventoryById(int? id) 
{
    return db.Inventories.Find(id);
}
```

And then your code works (you dont need to first create an empty `Inventory` though)

```
Inventory model = repository.FindInventoryById(id);
```

Comment: Yes you are right im very new to programming, been doingit for like to months. Got some basics. I was aware that i cant assign void to a variable but i just didnt know what to use instead, just started to learn about MVC.  However, this worked like a charm and i can see the logic to why i should use Inventory instead of void. Thanks alot mate.